# Really odd method in application

Tags: ruby

I just came across an odd method in some Ruby code, and I'm wondering if I'm missing something fundamental.  It looks like this:

```
def funny
  !funny
end
```

What would this possibly return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would recurse until you got a stack overflow.

Comment: Isn't the verb 'recur'? Sorry for being anal ;)

Comment: I think theres a recursive-recursive joke in there somewhere about posting recursive stack overflows errors in questions referring to recursion on StackOverflow

Answer (score 5):

That would run recursively until you get a stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

It is a method labelled as being funny, which then contains !funny or literally, "not funny".

It recurses until there is a stack overflow.